# Why each time a same address is allocated for the variable in local scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
            int x=i;
         cout<<&x<<endl;
    }
}
```

now each time it prints the same memory address. Now x is destroyed after each iteration as its only a local variable. But why then the address of x is always the same?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it be? What does it matter if it is (or isn't)? Such things are left up to the compiler and can be implemented differently on different systems as appropriate to that architecture.

Comment: Think about how the stack is used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136393/for-loop-local-variables-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at disassembly of the this program to understand what is going on.
Before start we can simplify it a little by replacing cout, endl -->> printf. There is nothing special but disassembled loop will be a little shorter.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
            int x=i;
            printf("%x\n",&x);
    }
}
```

Build `g++ -o main main.c`, run `./main`, disassemble with `objdump -d main`, the main disassembly with comments (meaningful lines are marked with "<<--", machine codes of commands are removed) :

```
0000000000400810 <main>:
400810: push   %rbp       ; prologue
400811: mov    %rsp,%rbp  ; --------
400814: sub    $0x10,%rsp ; <<-- Prepare place at stack 
                                           ;      for two 4-byte variables!
                                           ; Addr. space: 0x4 + 0x4 = 0x10
400818: movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)    ; init i with a 0
40081f: jmp    400841 <main+0x31> ; start loop -------------------.
400821: mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax    ; <<-- move i to eax <----------|-.
400824: mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)    ; <<-- move eax to x            | |
400827: lea    -0x8(%rbp),%rax    ; <<-- load effective           | |
                                  ; address of x to rax           | |
40082b: mov    %rax,%rsi          ; param - address of x          | |
40082e: mov    $0x400940,%edi     ; param - address of format str | |
400833: mov    $0x0,%eax          ; param - final zero            | |
400838: callq  4006a0 <printf@plt>; call printf(..)               | |
40083d: addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)    ; increment i                   | |
400841: cmpl   $0x4,-0x4(%rbp)    ; compare with 4     <----------' |     
400845: jle    400821 <main+0x11> ; if <= go to --------------------'
400847: mov    $0x0,%eax          ; default return value
40084c: jmp    400856 <main+0x46>
40084e: mov    %rax,%rdi
400851: callq  400710 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
400856: leaveq 
400857: retq
```

So compiler just move `x` outside the loop and holds it at stack. So as a result we have a constant address of `x`.
Tested on x86_64 with System V AMD64 ABI calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

Each x reuses the same memory space as the old x from the previous iteration, since the old one no longer needs it :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a compiler's contribution. The're designed with optimisation functionalities. You wolud have to check the compiler's output code to see why it is that way.