# How to prevent compiler from using the same address for a variable in a loop

Tags: c, gcc

In this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5; i++)
    {
         int h;
         printf("%p \n",&h);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is the same in each loop. As stated in other questions [For-loop Local Variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136393/for-loop-local-variables-in-c?lq=1), [Why each time a same address is allocated for the variable in local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102003/why-each-time-a-same-address-is-allocated-for-the-variable-in-local-scope?lq=1) this is happening because of a compiler optimization. I want to find a way to prevent this optimization in order to have different addresses each time I declare the variable h. I know I can use malloc and allocate different heap memory each time but I want to find a solution using stack memory. Is there a flag for gcc to disable this optimization?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why? Why? and thrice Why?

Comment: The option to tell the compiler to do this should be called -overflow-stack, I believe. (It is not an “optimization” if the alternative does not work at all.)

Comment: There are no reasons for H changes on the stack.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot expect to exert that sort of control over the compiler. It is entitled to put your variables wherever it likes.

If you need multiple variables, use an array.

```
int h[5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
     printf("%p \n",&h[i]);  
}
```

As Pascal astutely points out in the comments, your proposed feature will lead to stack overflows. I'm sure you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The problem with the array is that it doesn't work in all loops. I wrote the above loop just for simplicity to point out the problem. If you have a loop where you don't know when it stops before it begins , then you can't use arrays.

Comment: Your proposed alternative overflows the stack though. If you want multiple variables you use an array, either fixed size, or dynamically allocated.

Comment: I tried -overflow-stack but didn't work. The solution I am trying to find doesn't necessarily overflow the stack . It depends on the condition the loop has. I don't claim that this is the best solution, I just want to find out if there is such a solution.

Comment: The solution is as per my answer. @Pascal was being ironic in his comment. He selected the name -overflow-stack as a way to emphasise that what you are asking for has undesirable side effects.